# Assembly language program in x86 and x64

Tags: assembly

Can I write an assembly language program for which half of its instruction will run for x86(32-bit) processor and another for x64(64-bit) processor?
Is it possible? And not then why?

Comment: Yes it's possible, however it might not be easy to get the OS to load it.

Comment: Hi Arohi, is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_binary) what you are trying to describe?

Comment: Sure thing! Usually not useful though. You can switch between the 32bit and 64bit sub-modes if you're on a 64bit OS, just change CS to the right selector.